# MySQL Foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have four tables. Each of the first three should be referenced as foreign keys in the fourth table, substitutions.

Here is my advisers table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_adviser`.`advisers` (
   `adviser_id` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `middle_intial` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`adviser_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Here is the course_list table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_adviser`.`course_list` (
   `course_id` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   `course_name` VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
   `credit_hours` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

The students table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_adviser`.`students` (
   `student_id` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `middle_initial` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
   `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `adviser_id` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   `program_id` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   `concentration_id` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   `outside_concentration_id` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
   INDEX `program_id_idx` (`program_id` ASC),
   INDEX `concentration_id_idx` (`concentration_id` ASC),
   INDEX `outside_concentration_id_idx` (`outside_concentration_id` ASC),
   INDEX `adviser_id` (`adviser_id` ASC),
   INDEX `program_id` (`program_id` ASC, `concentration_id` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`adviser_id`)
   REFERENCES `virtual_adviser`.`advisers` (`adviser_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_2`
   FOREIGN KEY (`program_id` , `concentration_id`)
   REFERENCES `virtual_adviser`.`degree_program` (`program_id` , `concentration_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And last is the substitutions table, which causes the error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtual_adviser`.`substitutions` (
   `student_id` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   `adviser_id` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   `course_id` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   `course_sub` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`adviser_id`,`course_id`,`course_sub`),
   INDEX `course_id_idx` (`course_id` ASC),
   INDEX `student_id_idx` (`student_id` ASC),
   INDEX `FK_course_sub_idx` (`course_sub` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `substitutions_ibfk_1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `virtual_adviser`.`students` (`student_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `substitutions_ibfk_2`
   FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `virtual_adviser`.`course_list` (`course_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `substitutions_ibfk_3`
  FOREIGN KEY (`course_sub`) REFERENCES `virtual_adviser`.`course_list` (`course_id`)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I've tried creating the table with each of the foreign keys individually, but it doesn't make a difference, all of them trigger the same error. I've also checked that the data types are identical in the original and referencing table, and they are, so I don't believe that is the cause of the error. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here?

Comment: I can't seem to repeat an error [on SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/175fef), although did need to drop the schema (SqlFiddle security) and the constraint to `degree_program` given that the table wasn't provided.

Comment: I am able to get this to work in SQL Fiddle as well. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Comment: In the substitutions table only?

Comment: I would really double check your spelling everywhere in your original code because I can make this work in SQL Fiddle and the MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @David Farthing Do you have any `insert` statements in your original code after each `create` statment? If so, make sure to `create` all the tables first and only then `insert` the data.

Comment: @McAdam 331: Yes, I am only getting the "cannot add foreign key constraint" in the substitutions table. I'll try adding the table in MySQL Workbench, since I cannot get it to work as a create table statement. Thanks for your help